# android multitouch using sound pool

Tags: android, multi-touch, soundpool

i'm not sure how to correctly use onTouch. Right now I can press an image and play the sound, but I cannot play two sounds at once, nor can I slide my finger down and play all the sounds, it will only play the first image pressed. I know this is because of onTouch and Multitouch but i'm not sure how to do this and I can't find any relevant sample code, any help is appreciated!

this code onTouch , but i need Multitouch

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) {
             if(v.getId()==R.id.sagatup){

                if (loaded) {
                    soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
                }

             }
             if(v.getId()==R.id.sagatdown){

                if (loaded) {
                    soundPool.play(soundID2, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
                }
             }
             if(v.getId()==R.id.clap){

                // Is the sound loaded already?
                if (loaded) {
                    soundPool.play(soundID3, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
                }
             }
             if(v.getId()==R.id.za3rota){

                    // Is the sound loaded already?
                    if (loaded) {
                        soundPool2.play(soundID4, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                        Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
                    }
             }

        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will not work when sliding **the same finger** to trigger other presses. `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is triggered only once, when the user initially touches the screen, then multiple `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` events are sent until the user lifts **the same finger** that received the down event. Multi-touch should work as long as you use **multiple-fingers** to press the buttons and your device supports it.

Answer (score 0):

change `return false`; to
`return true`;